# MSIS7001: The passive protocol context was not found or not valid

Tags: adfs2.0

I am trying to federate one ADFS server with another ADFS server so that the Identity can be provided with the second ADFS instance. So Relying Party Application  --> RP ADFS 1 --> ID ADFS
1.I have the RP Application set up with a relying party trust in RP ADFS
2.I have the ID ADFS set up with a Claims Provider trust in the RP ADFS
3.I have the RP ADFS set up with a Relying Party Trust in the ID ADFS

When attempt to go to my relying part I am bounced to the ID ADFS logon page and I can Logon and it is bounced back to the RP ADFS where I receive the error.

```
MSIS7001: The passive protocol context was not found or not valid. 

Encountered error during federation passive request. 

Additional Data 

Exception details: 

Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.InvalidContextException: MSIS7001: The passive protocol context was not found or not valid. If the context was stored in cookies, the cookies that were presented by the client were not valid. Ensure that the client browser is configured to accept cookies from this website and retry this request.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.EncodedContext..ctor(String encodedValue, Boolean samlEnabled, Boolean wsFederationEnabled)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.ParseRelyingPartyInfoFromWCtx(String wctx, Boolean deleteCookie, String& contextId)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.GetOriginalRequest(FederationPassiveContext federationPassiveContext, Boolean deleteCookie, String& requestId)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.GetOriginalRequest(Boolean deleteCookie, String& requestId)
```

I have seen the [Question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/33518bc7-fffc-48de-a89a-d234ee598cb1/msis7001-the-passive-protocol-context-was-not-found-or-not-valid?forum=Geneva), and I have ensured that the answer has been followed.

I have also seen this[question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/47fbd023-7983-412c-82af-2d2de47e3ba8/msis7001-passive-protocol-context-error?forum=Geneva) and it's not clear what solution this one proposes.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a resolution to this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Got this issue now. So sad there’s no resolution here!
In my case I have both ADFS servers federated with each other, i.e. bi-directional access. It works one way, but not the other. Urgh.